# I am getting an error of UNSUPPORTED ENGINE while installing hardhat

Tags: solidity, dapps, nft, hardhat

[image]

Why am I not getting welcome to hardhat message?
I got it for my earlier projects
but not this one

Comment: You need to use Node v12 or above. I am voting to close this question because it is not a question about Ethereum. You can read about the `engines` field [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#engines).

Comment: According to the log @Yash Jagtap uses node v17.4.0 which is above v12, but somehow not supported by hardhat (yet), any version in the 12.X.X , 14.X.X or 16.X.X should work just fine.  see https://issueantenna.com/repo/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/2570

Answer (score 0):

You get the welcome message when you run `npx hardhat`.